# Postfix can't send mails to gmail - sender non-delivery notification

Tags: email, postfix, gmail, yahoo

Having some troubles sending mails to gmail with Postfix. Below is my log:

```
Nov 24 15:07:02 ubuntu-4gb-fsn1-1 postfix/pickup[101539]: 4C99C4225A: uid=33 from=<www-data>
Nov 24 15:07:02 ubuntu-4gb-fsn1-1 postfix/cleanup[101916]: 4C99C4225A: message-id=<20201124140702.4C99C4225A@ubuntu-4gb-fsn1-1>
Nov 24 15:07:02 ubuntu-4gb-fsn1-1 postfix/qmgr[65515]: 4C99C4225A: from=<www-data@my-domain.com>, size=329, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov 24 15:07:03 ubuntu-4gb-fsn1-1 postfix/smtp[101918]: 4C99C4225A: to=<recipient@yahoo.co.uk>, relay=mx-eu.mail.am0.yahoodns.net[188.125.72.74]:25, d
elay=0.91, delays=0.02/0.01/0.34/0.52, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 ok dirdel)
Nov 24 15:07:03 ubuntu-4gb-fsn1-1 postfix/qmgr[65515]: 4C99C4225A: removed
Nov 24 15:07:58 ubuntu-4gb-fsn1-1 postfix/pickup[101539]: 9552D4225A: uid=33 from=<www-data>
Nov 24 15:07:58 ubuntu-4gb-fsn1-1 postfix/cleanup[101916]: 9552D4225A: message-id=<20201124140758.9552D4225A@ubuntu-4gb-fsn1-1>
Nov 24 15:07:58 ubuntu-4gb-fsn1-1 postfix/qmgr[65515]: 9552D4225A: from=<www-data@my-domain.com>, size=332, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov 24 15:07:59 ubuntu-4gb-fsn1-1 postfix/smtp[101918]: 9552D4225A: to=<recipient@googlemail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:400c:c0c::1b]:25, delay=0.76, delays=0.01/0/0.13/0.61, dsn=5.7.1, status=bounced (host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:400c:c0c::1b] said: 550-5.7.1 [2a01:4f8:c010:3127::1] Our system has detected that this message does 550-5.7.1 not meet IPv6 sending guidelines regarding PTR records and 550-5.7.1 authentication. Please review 550-5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=IPv6AuthError for more information 550 5.7.1 . n11si2614598wma.157 - gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA command))
Nov 24 15:07:59 ubuntu-4gb-fsn1-1 postfix/cleanup[101916]: 5B1304225D: message-id=<20201124140759.5B1304225D@ubuntu-4gb-fsn1-1>
Nov 24 15:07:59 ubuntu-4gb-fsn1-1 postfix/bounce[101930]: 9552D4225A: sender non-delivery notification: 5B1304225D
Nov 24 15:07:59 ubuntu-4gb-fsn1-1 postfix/qmgr[65515]: 5B1304225D: from=<>, size=3011, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov 24 15:07:59 ubuntu-4gb-fsn1-1 postfix/qmgr[65515]: 9552D4225A: removed
Nov 24 15:07:59 ubuntu-4gb-fsn1-1 postfix/local[101931]: 5B1304225D: to=<www-data@my-domain.com>, relay=local, delay=0.01, delays=0/0.01/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Nov 24 15:07:59 ubuntu-4gb-fsn1-1 postfix/qmgr[65515]: 5B1304225D: removed
Nov 24 15:20:21 ubuntu-4gb-fsn1-1 postfix/pickup[101539]: 714A94225D: uid=33 from=<www-data>
Nov 24 15:20:21 ubuntu-4gb-fsn1-1 postfix/cleanup[102121]: 714A94225D: message-id=<20201124142021.714A94225D@ubuntu-4gb-fsn1-1>
Nov 24 15:20:21 ubuntu-4gb-fsn1-1 postfix/qmgr[65515]: 714A94225D: from=<www-data@my-domain.com>, size=328, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov 24 15:20:21 ubuntu-4gb-fsn1-1 postfix/smtp[102123]: 714A94225D: host mx1.pub.mailpod9-cph3.one.com[185.164.14.118] said: 450 4.7.1 138.119.249.183 temporary greylisted by CYREN IP reputation (in reply to MAIL FROM command)
Nov 24 15:20:21 ubuntu-4gb-fsn1-1 postfix/smtp[102123]: 714A94225D: lost connection with mx1.pub.mailpod9-cph3.one.com[185.164.14.118] while sending RCPT TO
Nov 24 15:20:22 ubuntu-4gb-fsn1-1 postfix/smtp[102123]: 714A94225D: to=<contact@lauthiamkok.net>, relay=mx3.pub.mailpod9-cph3.one.com[185.164.14.120]:25, delay=0.92, delays=0.02/0.02/0.82/0.07, dsn=4.7.1, status=deferred (host mx3.pub.mailpod9-cph3.one.com[185.164.14.120] said: 450 4.7.1 138.119.249.183 temporary greylisted by CYREN IP reputation (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
Nov 24 15:27:09 ubuntu-4gb-fsn1-1 postfix/qmgr[65515]: 714A94225D: from=<www-data@my-domain.com>, size=328, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov 24 15:27:10 ubuntu-4gb-fsn1-1 postfix/smtp[102169]: 714A94225D: host mx3.pub.mailpod9-cph3.one.com[185.164.14.120] said: 450 4.7.1 138.119.249.183 temporary greylisted by CYREN IP reputation (in reply to MAIL FROM command)

Nov 24 15:27:10 ubuntu-4gb-fsn1-1 postfix/smtp[102169]: 714A94225D: lost connection with mx3.pub.mailpod9-cph3.one.com[185.164.14.120] while sending RCPT TO
Nov 24 15:27:10 ubuntu-4gb-fsn1-1 postfix/smtp[102169]: 714A94225D: to=<contact@other-email.net>, relay=mx2.pub.mailpod9-cph3.one.com[185.164.14.119]:25, delay=409, delays=408/0.02/0.57/0.05, dsn=4.7.1, status=deferred (host mx2.pub.mailpod9-cph3.one.com[185.164.14.119] said: 450 4.7.1 138.119.249.183 temporary greylisted by CYREN IP reputation (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
(END)
```

You can see that no issue with yahoo. But you get a `sender non-delivery notification` for gmail.

Any ideas why?

My Postfix config:

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_security_level=may

smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level=may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = ubuntu-4gb-fsn1-1
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = my-domain.com, $myhostname, ubuntu-4gb-fsn1-1, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
inet_protocols = all
```

Comment: Your Postfix logs look incomplete. They don't show what was the result of the mail send attempt (accept or reject), and if rejected, what was the rejection message - that's very important. Have the lines been truncated somehow (">" at the end of the line, where the rest of the message should be, suggests that)? Also, what was written in the non-delivery notification?

Comment: You don't have **relayhost** identified.

Comment: Did you check the bounce messages?  NORMALLY Google requires you to go above and beyond to make postfix work with sending to their mail servers.  (DKIM, SPF, forward DNS HELO in Postfix matching the rDNS exactly, etc.)  so if this is your own home system/server you're not going to be able to get anything resolved.

Comment: @heynnema relayhost isn't necessarily needed unless they're configuring it to go via GMail as a relay.  Which requires a lot more complex configuration to get working, but it might not work in the modern way of Google doing their authentication mechanisms anymore.

Comment: @ThomasWard I don't believe that Google's smtp servers like talking to unrecognized home servers. And you're correct, it may require more configuration.

Comment: @heynnema I think it best to figure out what OP is trying to do first - no relayhost configured sounds likea  HOme Server not a Relay case, so relayhost being 'blank' is normal for a standard SMTP server deployment (but you're right, 'home servers' usually are blacklisted by most blacklists and systems because they're impossible to get into 'compliance' and usually used by malware/hijacked systems)

Comment: @ThomasWard it is a live production server. Not home one. How do I configure Postfix for google then?

Answer (score 1):

You have the reason fully explained in the bounce message from Google:

550-5.7.1 [2a01:4f8:c010:3127::1] Our system has detected that this message does 550-5.7.1 not meet IPv6 sending guidelines regarding PTR records and 550-5.7.1 authentication. Please review 550-5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=IPv6AuthError for more information

So you have to read information at the specified URL and configure your mailserver as specified there.

Also note that some other receiving host is saying to you: 450 4.7.1 138.119.249.183 temporary greylisted by CYREN IP reputation. Your server's IP is indicated as a "bad reputation" at some service called CYREN (sorry, I don't know what it is - you have to look up for yourself). You may need to resolve the issue as well to get your mail delivered to Google, as Google is very sensitive to "bad reputation" IPs.

Comment: To summarize this: Set up SPF records for your domain, have it HELO with an actual domain name not your systme hostname, have the HELO exist in DNS to the IP address of your mail server, wherever your mail server runs have the provider set the reverse DNS to match the HELO name (needs to be normal DNS), set up DKIM signatures, and have **patience** becuase it takes time for Google to recognize you as legit mail servers.